# Getting undefined in formdata in firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have created a REST API endpoint using firebase cloud functions.  I am sending

```
name: xyz
```

When I post form data to it using postman, I get following.

`request.body.name` return undefined in the following code.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {


    console.log( request.body.name );


    if( request.method != "POST" ){
        return response.status(500).json({
            'status': true,
            'error': 'HTTP Method Not Allowed'
        });
    }

        var name = request.query.name;    
        response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
    }


});
```

Comment: FYI, you are using both `request.body.name` and `request.query.name` in your code.

Comment: Please be more specific about how you are sending the data.  Are you sending it as JSON in a POST body, or are you sending key/value pairs in the query string?